# Java - Creating Github v3 Public Key

Tags: java, ssh, github

I can't figure this one out. I'm trying to dynamically roll keys. I can create the POST request fine, but receive a 400 error and a stacktrace with an `IOException` when I call `post`. Below is a self-contained example.  I'm using `JSCH` to generate keys. API doc: http://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/

The API call: `POST /user/keys`

```
public static class LiberalHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}

public static String post(String requestUrl, Map<String, String> params,
    String username, String password) throws Exception {
    String data = "";
    int paramCount = 1;
    for (Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (paramCount == 1) {
            data = URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8");
        } else {
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8");
        }
        paramCount++;
    }
    URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) (url).openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setHostnameVerifier(new LiberalHostnameVerifier());
    BASE64Encoder enc = new BASE64Encoder();
    String userAuth = username + ":" + password;
    String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode(userAuth.getBytes());
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    String response = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response += line;
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
    return response;
}

public static KeyPair generateKey(String filename) throws Exception {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try {
        KeyPair kpair = KeyPair.genKeyPair(jsch, KeyPair.RSA);
        kpair.setPassphrase("");
        kpair.writePrivateKey(filename + ".pem");
        kpair.writePublicKey(filename + ".pub", "Auto-generated.");
        System.out.println("Finger print: " + kpair.getFingerPrint());
        // kpair.dispose();
        return kpair;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getFileContents(File file) throws Exception {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
    f.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}

public static String createKey(String title) throws Exception {
    generateKey(title);
    final String key = getFileContents(new File(
            "/Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/" + title
                + ".pub"));
    System.out.println("key: " + key);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>() {

        {
            put("title", title);
            put("key", key);
        }
    };
    return post("https://api.github.com/user/keys", params, "username",
        "password");
}
```

// call createKey("key);

Comment: Strange, 401 is a security error. Do you have any authorization framework ? Maybe there is a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) issue somewhere...

Comment: So, you were correct -- stupid credential issue that I missed.  One more step in the right direction!  Now I get a 400 response, but don't see a message returned that is useful. I created a "SimpleRestClient" class to double check things, updating code now.

Comment: 400 is a [Bad request](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html). So it comes from your client. Test with another client, like [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nico_ekito and @J-16 SDiZ for helping in the right direction.  If you look closely at the documentation, the request doesn't use standard POST parameters, but rather takes JSON as Raw Input, and the ssh-rsa key can NOT be encoded. Next up, I can't get GSON to not encode a string, even using `disableHtmlEscaping`. So, I had to fake it:

```
String json = "{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"key\":\"" + key.trim() + "\"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a ssh library (e.g. [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)). They can generate RSA key in [SSH consumable format](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/KeyGen.java).

Comment: Hmm...I didn't.  I will try that out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Still getting a 401. But closer! Updating for new method.